# Вставка элементов в список

Tags: c++, список, односвязный-список

Односвязный список, есть две функции вставки элемента в конец списка и в начало списка. Вот они.
Функция вставки элемента в начало списка:

```
void addToStart(TStud * &Start, TStud * PNew)
{
PNew->next=Start; // В новый элемент в поле Next заносится 
                  // адрес предыдущего первого элемента
Start=PNew;       // Переменной Start заносится адрес нового элемента
}
```

Функция вставки в конец списка:

```
    void addToEnd(TStud * &Start, TStud * PNew)
  {
  TStud * WP;       // объявления рабочего указателя
  PNew->next=NULL;  // новый элемент в любом случае будет последним
  if (Start == NULL)// если список пуст
     {
      Start=PNew;   // новый элемент становится первым и последним элементом
      return;       // выход из функции, элемент добавлен в список
     }
  WP=Start;         // инициализация рабочего указателя первым элементом
  while(WP->next!=NULL)  // цикл прохода по списку пока WP - не последний
     {
      WP=WP->next;  // в WP заносим адрес следующего элемента
     }
                    // теперь WP удерживает адрес последнего элемента списка
   WP->next=PNew;   // «Привязываем» новый элемент до последнего
  }
```

Теперь сам вопрос. Можно ли эти функции объединить?
Т.е  чтобы вместо двух функцию была одна, которая определяла самостоятельно куда нужно вставить элемент в зависимости от его значения ( максимальный элемент в конец списка, минимальный в начало списка ).
Объясните как это можно сделать?

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вам нужно что-то типа `set`? То есть чтобы элементы списка располагались по возрастанию.

Comment: ну мне нужно чтобы функция вставляла элемент либо в начало либо в конец списка, если элемент меньше чем остальные то он вставляется в начало, если больше то в конец.

Comment: Допустим есть уже есть числа: `1 2 4 ` и вы хотите вставить `5` тут понятно, что будет `1 2 3 5`, если же `0`, то `0 1 2 3 5`, а если вы захотите вставить `4`??? Куда её вставлять?

Comment: Короткий ответ: нет, это разные функции. Можно написать функцию-обёртку, которая будет вызывать соответствующую по какому-либо условию.